# CSRF protection for oauth authorization

Tags: csrf, oauth2

I've read a lot about the state parameter in oauth flow. But i cant quite understand if the state validation helps my use case.

end to end flow:

1. resource owner is redirected to service provider site([github](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/apps/building-oauth-apps/authorizing-oauth-apps#2-users-are-redirected-back-to-your-site-by-github))
2. authorizes client
3. redirects back to client site with code
4. code is forwarded to client backend with cookie.
5. backend fetches the access token from service provider for the code and client secret. service provider resource is saved in the client backend for the resource owner

possible Attack:

1. Attacker tricks the user to receive his service provider code

...

2. backend saved attacker's service provider resource for victim user

assuming this is not a problem/ does not favor the attacker, is it still required to validate user specific state?
am i missing any other attacks Im not protected against, if i dont validate the state?

Comment: When the Identity Provider (IdP) redirects back, it will return the same state that you sent to the IdP in the authroization code request. You are supposed to always verify if the state matches before processing the response.

Comment: i understand, @defalt. But I dont understand why do we need to verify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **CSRF** attacks on Oauth2/OIDC if the state is not used works like this:

1. Alice knows client ID and redirect URI of your web service.
2. Alice tricks Bob to visit her web app.
3. As soon as Bob visits her web app, it crafts an URL encoded authorization request by using client ID and redirect URI of your web service and redirects Bob to the sign in page of the Identity Provider (IdP).

   **But why?** It's because if the Bob is not signed in to your web app, this will start the login process and unless Bob is not signed into your web app, Alice cannot send any user action to your web service APIs.
4. It's likely that Bob is already signed in at IdP so the IdP sends authorization code to the callback endpoint of your web service in the redirect response.
5. Your callback endpoint will use the authorization code to exchange token and set cookies which will sign Bob in even though Bob has never visited your web app.

By using `state`, you prevent #5 from executing token exchange and setting cookies. When the callback endpoint receives authorization code from the IdP in the redirect response, it should first obtain `state` from cookies because Alice cannot set cookies for your web app and match its value with the state returned by the IdP. If there is no state, that means your web app never initiated sign in so you can block further execution.

Comment: Thanks for explaining @defalt. Still i need clarity :/
1. "it should first obtain state from cookies". But, there are no cookies in the redirect response.
2. so bob is logged into the web app tricked by alice. but is it really a problem?

Comment: Your web app is supposed to set cookie that stores state before making an authorization request. The redirect response will have this cookie. Once Bob is signed in, Alice web app can then send a request to your web service to perform a user action in Bob's account.

Answer (score 1):

While OAuth (or, if you're doing it right, OIDC) without State can be used for logging in a user to your app unexpectedly (as in [defalt's answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/266559/53333)), that's only rarely a problem. It may confuse the user, and if your site has any (other) CSRF vulnerabilities then an attacker could potentially use this attack to ensure the victim is logged in prior to launching CSRF attacks, but otherwise it's generally just not a big deal for a user to be unexpectedly logged into their own account on a site. However, there are cases where the State parameter is necessary to prevent more serious attacks.

1. Login CSRF: an attacker waits until a victim visits their site, then launches their own server-side flow to connect to the authorization server, authorize using an attacker-controlled account, and obtain the code. The attacker then redirects the victim's browser to your OAuth callback URL with the code that the attacker just retrieved, which corresponds to an account they control. The victim's browser never visits the authorization server in this process. The attacker forcibly logs the victim in to an attacker-chosen account on your app. If the victim - expecting to be logged in under their own account - then takes any action that they wouldn't want the attacker to see (e.g. uploads a file, sends a message, enters sensitive payment info or PII or similar, etc.) or collects any app-generated sensitive data (e.g. account number of cryptocurrency address where they'll ask somebody to send funds), then the attacker can also log into the same account on your app and see what the victim did / benefit from the victim giving their address to the third party. Note that mitigating login CSRF in full generality is often difficult, and relatively few sites bother, but for some it's important.
2. Account linking. On some sites, a user might have multiple ways to log in. Perhaps there's a legacy account that can be accessed via username+password or other user-supplied credentials, but users can also log in via SSO. For convenience, most of these sites allow users to link an SSO account to a legacy login account, such that either SSO or site-specific credentials can be used to log in to the same account. If a victim is already logged into their own account on your site (via credentials of some sort) and visits an attacker-controlled page, the attacker can launch an attack similar to the one above (forcing the user to finish the OAuth flow with an attacker-chosen SSO account) but rather than logging in to a new account, link the victim's existing account to the attacker-chosen SSO account. The attacker can then visit your site directly, choose "log in with SSO", and use the same SSO account to log into the victim's existing account on your site, gaining full account compromise.
3. Resource provider. While you might be using OAuth just for SSO, this is not actually what it's designed for (and if you want to use SSO, you should be using OIDC on top of OAuth). The primary purpose of OAuth is to authorize an app (yours) to connect to resources provided by another app (e.g. calendar, chat, documents, gaming, etc.), specifically in the context of the user. For example, you might ask users to link their account (on your site) to their Github account so that you can do something that embeds or extends GH functionality in some way, like automatically uploading files created within your app to a new repo on the user's GH profile. In this case, an attacker could link a GH account that the attacker controls to the victim's account on your app (same flow as before, with the attacker having the victim's browser submit the authorization code that the attacker retrieved), and then when the victim did something in your app, the resulting files would appear in a GH account that the attacker has access to!

---

There exist scenarios where none of the above attacks are of significant concern, and in such cases, you might be able to get away without using / verifying the State parameter. However, even if you're *really* sure that your app is one where CSRF on the OAuth flow doesn't matter... why take the risk? Maybe it'll become relevant in the future and you'll forget to fix your OAuth flow then. Or maybe a new attack on no-State OAuth flows will be invented, and your app will care about it. Or maybe your app will get big and some security researcher will poke around it and find that you don't check State, and make a big hullabaloo about how your app doesn't follow basic security best practices. Anyhow, the point is, it's a cheap thing to do - just generate a secure random string, and then either store it in a cookie on the client or in server-side user/session data (the latter is more secure but takes more server resources) as well as including it when starting OAuth flows, and verify the returned parameter when the code (and accompanying State) are sent to your OAuth callback endpoint.

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer. +1 for the advice. +1 for Schneier's Law